# Metro app, don't freeze UI

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, winrt-async

I'm writing a metro application with a lot of call to webservice.
Sometimes the web service is a bit slow. And I don't want to wait within a page until my data are downloaded.

But, my back button is disabled until my data have been loaded.
Which is a big problem.

So I tried with :

```
 try
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
                       {
                           Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High, 
                           () => ViewModel.InitAsync(date)).AsTask(_cts.Token);
                       }, _cts.Token);
}catch(Exception e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("HomePage, LoadState : "+e);
}
```

Note;

I use Task.Run to be able to use a cancellationtoken.
And Dispatcher.RunAsync should allow me to not freeze my UI.
This is used within page LoadState.

How could I fix this issue ?

Regards.

Updated with (doesn't fix my issue):

```
try
{
    Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    ViewModel.InitAsync(date)).AsTask(_cts.Token);
}catch(Exception e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("HomePage, LoadState : "+e);
}
```

Comment: Where does this code appear? I suspect you still don't need `Task.Run`, given that you can specify the cancellation token in the `AsTask` call.

Comment: @JonSkeet it appears during page load state.

Comment: Well there you are then - you don't finish page loading until the web service call has completed. Even though you aren't making the UI thread block, I suspect the back button appearing is tied to page load completion.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks, I tried to add this within my loaded event (so It should do that when my page is loaded). But this doesn't fix my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just throw `Task.Run` and `Dispatcher.RunAsync` at your problems. You need to understand what they do.

In your case, you should be able to just do this:

```
try
{
  await ViewModel.InitAsync(date);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  Debug.WriteLine("HomePage, LoadState : " + e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't solve my issue and I want it to be in another thread than the UI (to improve performance). And I also want to use a task to be able to cancel it.

Comment: If `InitAsync` is a correctly-written asynchronous method, then you won't improve performance by running it in another thread. And you can just modify `InitAsync` to take a `CancellationToken`.